# Hand-coded log function won't find base-10 logs over 10

Tags: c, math, logarithm

As an assignment I'm coding a log function using the hi-lo method to find the answer, but what I have doesn't work for numbers greater than 10 and I can't figure out why

```
int main() {
  double n, nq, x, y;
  printf("Enter the number you wish to take to the base 10 logarithm:\n");
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  double hi = 1;
  double lo = 0;
  double qlo = 1;
  double qhi = 10;

  for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    n = ((lo + hi)/2);
    nq = sqrt(qlo * qhi);
    if(nq > x) {
      hi = n;
      qhi = nq;
    } else {
      lo = n;
      qlo = nq;
    }
  }
  y = n;

  printf("the logarithm is equal to %lf\n", y);
  printf("%lf\n", log10(x)); // to check result
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting? Does the value converge? Or is it just wrong?

Comment: Any input higher than 10 results in 1.00000

Comment: A 'fix' which you might want to consider is to use the identity `log(n) == 1+log(n/10)` for numbers outside the range `1..10`.

Comment: Since the point is to program the log function, I can't use the library function in my code

Comment: Because a function was requested, consider moving your algorithm to own function from the main. For example: `double my_log10(double x)`

Comment: Be careful with this: `n = (lo + hi) / 2;` It is dangerous to calculate averages that way, and you should only use it if you know for sure that `lo` and `hi` have absolutely no possibility of being higher that `INT_MAX / 2`.  A safer but slower way to do the average is `(a / 2) + (b / 2) + (((a % 2) + (b % 2)) / 2);`.  It would be a good idea to write a macro `AVG(a, b)` to encapsulate that logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Enter the number you wish to take to the base 10 logarithm:
1234.5678
50 iterations found 3.091514945509
```

See changes below...

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  double x, y;
  printf("Enter the number you wish to take to the base 10 logarithm:\n");
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  double hi = 1;
  double lo = 0;
  double qlo = 1;
  double qhi = 10;

  /*if (x <= 0) handle exception log undefined for input <= 0*/

  double tmp = 0;
  while (x > 10)
  {
    tmp++;
    x /= 10;
  }

  int i;
  double n = 0, nprev = -1;
  for (i = 0; i <= 1000 && fabs(n - nprev) > 1.0E-15; i++) 
  {
        nprev = n;
    n = ((lo + hi) / 2);
    double nq = sqrt(qlo * qhi);
    if (nq > x) 
    {
      hi = n;
      qhi = nq;
    }
    else 
    {
      lo = n;
      qlo = nq;
    }
  }
  y = tmp + n;
  printf("%2d iterations found %.12f",i,y);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In setting `qhi` to 10 you have bounded your result to 10. Setting `hi` to 1 is not helping either. So any input greater than 10 will return the value 1.

You need to be more sensible in your choices for `hi`, `lo`, `qlo`, and `qhi` if you want your function to work with a larger domain.

Comment: @Sil To avoid this, never use magic numbers, and instead write a macro giving them a meaningful name.  That way you will be forced to think what those numbers mean, and it will be easier to choose a right value

Answer (score 2):

This is close to a mathematical problem. Your function is able to compute an approximation of log<sub>10</sub>(x) **for any value x in the range [1:10]**. The rationale behind is simple: log<sub>10</sub>(1) is 0, log<sub>10</sub>(10) is 1 and log<sub>10</sub>(sqrt(a*b)) is 1/2(log<sub>10</sub>(a)+log<sub>10</sub>(b)).

So you build 2 sequences, the first one using dichotomy to approximate x, the second one will approximate log<sub>10</sub>(x).

Simply you must respect the following constraint: 1<=x<=10.

The common way is to write x = m 10<sup>n</sup> with 1<=m<10. Just divide (resp. multiply) x by ten until it falls in the correct range if it is >=10 (resp <=1). Then you get trivially: log<sub>10</sub>(x) = n + log<sub>10</sub>(m). And do not even try a negative value...